# Combinatorics question with stars and planets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Assume that a small universe has 10 distinct stars and 100 distinct planets so that 20 of them are habitable
and 80 of them are nonhabitable by humans. How many ways are there to form a galaxy with exactly one
star, 2 habitable planets and 8 nonhabitable planets such that there is at least six nonhabitable planets
between the two habitable ones?

Note: For this question, a galaxy is a bound system with a star at the center and a group of planets that
orbit the star. Different orders of the planets create different galaxies.

Comment: Hmm why didn't they just call these "galaxies" solar systems?

Comment: Is there a galaxy where people explain the problem they have with their maths questions before dumping them on math.se site?

Answer (score 3):

We start by choosing a star. There are $\binom{10}{1}$ ways to do this. We then choose our two habitable planets and $8$ non-habitables, which are the quantities: $\binom{20}{2}$ and $\binom{80}{8}$ respectively.

There are nine slots between the non-habitable planets, including before an after. You can visualize it below:

**_N_N_N_N_N_N_N_N_**

The first planet can only be in one of the first three slots. So if it is in the first slot, then there are $3$ options for habitable two. If it is in the second slot, there are two options for habitable planet $2$. And if it is in the third slot, we have only one option for habitable planet two. Notice this quantity is $\binom{4}{2}$.

And so by rule of product, we multiply to get our final answer:

$$\binom{10}{1} \binom{20}{2} \binom{80}{8} \binom{4}{2}$$

Edit: If the planets are distinct objects, we would multiply the above quantity by $2! 8!$. Permute the habitables and permute non-habitables.

Comment: Should the last factor be $6$ instead of $\binom{3}{2}$?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the catch! The binomial quantity is $\binom{4}{2}$. Sorry about that. :-)

Comment: Actually, I think the ordering is important since the planets are distinct. So maybe it also needs to be multiplied by $2!8!$? What do you think?

Comment: That's a good point. I updated to note that! :-)

Comment: yeah,their order is also important in my opinion we should use factorial multiplication.